# signin function return localStorage with one missing field

Tags: node.js, express, nestjs

I'm implementing a signin function, and push in a userRole array some data. Then i console.log this array and everything is fine, but finally when i return an object with userRole in it, it's empty.
Any idea why the return seems to be executed before userRole array is filled ?

```
  async signIn(user: User) {
    const userRoles: string[] = [];
    const payload = { username: user.username, sub: user._id };

    try {
      await this.userModel.findOne({
        username: user.username
      })
        .populate("roles", "-__v")
        .exec((err, user: User) => {
          for (let i = 0; i < user.roles.length; i++) {
            const role: string =  user.roles[i]['name']
            userRoles.push("ROLE_" + role.toUpperCase());
          }
          console.log('user roles: ', userRoles); // user roles:  [ 'ROLE_USER' ]
        })
    } catch (error) {
      if (error.code === 404) {
        throw new NotFoundException('User Not found');
      }
      throw error;
    }

    return {
      accessToken: this.jwtService.sign(payload),
      userId: user._id,
      email: user.email,
      roles: userRoles
    };
  }
```

See what i get from application tab > localStorage in chrome,  the 'roles' field is empty
but i except to have it like **[ 'ROLE_USER' ]**

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

you're mixing callbacks and async/await: you pass callback to `.exec` so async/await don't work, and return fires before the query

you need to pick one:

1. callbacks - remove async/await, and return from `.exec` callback:

```
signIn(user: User) {
        const userRoles: string[] = [];
        const payload = {
            username: user.username,
            sub: user._id
        };
        this.userModel.findOne({
            username: user.username
        })
        .populate("roles", "-__v")
        .exec((error, user: User) => {
            if(error) {
              if (error.code === 404) {
                  throw new NotFoundException('User Not found');
              }
              throw error;
            }
            for (let i = 0; i < user.roles.length; i++) {
                const role: string = user.roles[i]['name']
                userRoles.push("ROLE_" + role.toUpperCase());
            }
            console.log('user roles: ', userRoles); // user roles:  [ 'ROLE_USER' ]
            return {
                accessToken: this.jwtService.sign(payload),
                userId: user._id,
                email: user.email,
                roles: userRoles
            };
        })
    }
```

2. promises - remove callback from `exec` to get a "fully-fledged promise"

```
async signIn(user: User) {
    const userRoles: string[] = [];
    const payload = {
        username: user.username,
        sub: user._id
    };
    try {
        const data: User = await this.userModel.findOne({
            username: user.username
        })
        .populate("roles", "-__v")
        .exec(); // returns "fully-fledged promise"
        
        for (let i = 0; i < data.roles.length; i++) {
            const role: string = data.roles[i]['name']
            userRoles.push("ROLE_" + role.toUpperCase());
        }

        console.log('user roles: ', userRoles); // user roles:  [ 'ROLE_USER' ]

    } catch (error) {
        if (error.code === 404) {
            throw new NotFoundException('User Not found');
        }
        throw error;
    }
    return {
        accessToken: this.jwtService.sign(payload),
        userId: user._id,
        email: user.email,
        roles: userRoles
    };
}
```

check [Queries are not promises](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html)